# Wrapping a webapp in into a Windows 8 "Metro" App WITHOUT an iFrame

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to wrap our web app into a Windows 8 "Metro-style" app.

When you set up a Javascript style app in Visual Studio for Win8, it creates a "default.html" file. I was able to successfully use an iframe to load our web app, but this solution is inelegant and buggy. Namely, there are resources that cannot be loaded from within an iframe, causing problems (eg, `FORBIDIFRAME` error).

In OSX, I accomplished the same thing by simply using an embedded web browser and a Javascript bridge. The browser directly loads the web app URL, instead of using a local HTML file with an embedded iFrame as a proxy.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in Windows 8? Or am I forced to use a local HTML file and load our webapp in an IFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an Xaml-based project instead, and add a full-size [WebView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) with your website loaded on it.